# Apache Has Default URL Rewrites

Tags: php, apache2

So I just ran across this oddity.  It appears that Ubuntu has a "feature" (or bug) that allows you to access the same file using differing methods.

```
<domain>/phpinfo.php
<domain>/phpinfo/somthinghere
```

It seems that both of these load the same file.  I would like to turn this off but so far haven't found a way to do so.  Any Debian/Ubuntu folks out there know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this more an Apache issue than a Ubuntu one? (As in, answering the question would require knowledge of Apache, rather than Ubuntu.)

Comment: @Robin, yea, but he may be a Windows Convert, and I don't think the Windows WAMP install does `multiviews` by default. Even so, I modified the title etc to be a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you paste the virtual hosts file?

My bet is [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html), you need to remove the

```
 Options -MultiViews
```

`MultiViews` from the option section, or put a - before it.

Comment: Thanks for the module name, we turned that off and problem solved.  You guys are great.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is default enabling of this option called [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options)

You can disable it by having a line like this in your apache config or .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: There was hardly a 8 sec difference, +1 to you for spotting it together :)

Comment: Thanks guys, both of you.  I wish I could click you both.  Thanks for the quick response.  The only reason I accepted the solution below is he gave me the module name.  Props to both tho.